# Utility method checking if input is numeric - implementation advice

Tags: apex, method

How can I create an apex method inside a utility class that checks if field's value is numeric?

```
public class ErrorHandler{

public static boolean IsValueNumeric(object tv)
    {
        boolean toReturn=false;
        if(tv.isNumeric)
        {
            string t=String.valueOf(tv);            
            toReturn=!String.isNumeric(t);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked several times around SFSE. Have you done any research at all? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've included the code in my post already. Just want to make sure if the logic's correct enough, though.

Comment: @slsfrc It works

Comment: @slsfrc I don't think I'll make the edit myself, but I think the title and leading sentence of your question are completely different from what you're actually asking (based on your previous comment). Perhaps a better title would be "Utility method checking if input is numeric - implementation advice"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `instanceof` here:

```
public static Boolean isValueNumeric(Object value)
{
    return value instanceOf Double;
}
```

Some tests can confirm its veracity:

```
system.assert(isValueNumeric(20));
system.assert(isValueNumeric(3.14));
system.assert(!isValueNumeric('0'));
```

Comment: Awesome! Learned something, I was about to post `isNumeric()` but this is... nifty. Also, I liked the depth of the word [**Veracity**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/veracity), new again. :D